# How to run mantelhaen.test() and/or how to prepare data for it?

Tags: r

I want to perform a test on this data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Freq = c(41L, 31L, 11L, 0L), group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Survived = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried to follow along https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_06.html (and other tutorials like https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/samplesizeCMH/vignettes/samplesizeCMH-introduction.html ) but I can't get the data into the right format. How do I do?

Comment: That test is for data with three nominal variables.  Your example data has only two. You could use a regular Chi-squared test instead.

Comment: Thank you, but e.g. on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/samplesizeCMH/vignettes/samplesizeCMH-introduction.html they also only use Sex and Survived?

Comment: ah, sorry, it looks like you're right..  ok, then thanks for the help! :)